# how to get date and compare it while indexing

Tags: solr

I want to make a bust for latest data while indexing my content. For example 
Content from now to 6 months past should have boost = 10
and Content from 6 month past to 12 month past should have boost = 5
Older content should have boost = 0

my date is saved as timestamp so the only problem is to get current date while indexing

I can get date of content from row that is a param in my function but I don't know how to get current date and compare it. should it be something like this ?

and one more question

is there some way to check the boost ? I mean can i monitor what is boosted how ? Cause using result list with couple thousands articles is hard to mesure

// EDIT ANSWER

GOT IT

The script should look like this (this is for one 1 year past and older

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
function s1(row)    {
var curTime = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var itemDate = row.get('publication_date');
if(itemDate >= (curTime - 31104000)) {
    row.put('$docBoost', 40);
} else {
    row.put('$docBoost', 20);    
}

return row;
}
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using query/search time boosting instead for your use case. The main advantage is that you don't need to reindex your documents periodically to adjust boosts. See [Date Boosting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Date_Boosting) and ["How can I boost the score of newer documents"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) wiki tips

Comment: i found this samples BUT i would like to do it while indexing the content. I'm doing it at least one a day and I want it to be recalculated every time and also I don't want to make my query more complicated